# Enable the same user with multiple codes using ASP.NET MVC and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have created my first application using ASP.NET MVC and C#.

In the `controller.cs` I use the code as shown below to recognize whether the user (`tUser`) is registered in the database table `tUser` - or not.

If the user exists in the table `tUser` I set the session.

I don't have problem if the user registered has associated only one code (`tCode`), e.g.

```
+-----------------+--------+
| tUser           | tCode  |
+-----------------+--------+
| DOMAIN\Edward   | D11SU1 |
+-----------------+--------+
```

But how can I manage a user enabled with multiple codes?

e.g.

```
+-----------------+--------+
| tUser           | tCode  |
+-----------------+--------+
| DOMAIN\Edward   | D11SU1 |
| DOMAIN\Edward   | D11SU2 |
+-----------------+--------+
```

I using this information later  for populated a drop down list according to the enabling code. I'm going to use a query with WHERE condition e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE tCode IN ('D11SU1','D11SU2')
```

Is that possible?

This is my code:

```
private void recognizeuser()
{
    try
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;

        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(cs))
        {
            string commandText = " SELECT `tUser`, `tCode` FROM `tUser` " +
                " WHERE `tUser` = @Username; ";

            using (var command = new MySqlCommand(commandText, connection))
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString()))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString());
                }

                connection.Open();

                string tUser = string.Empty;
                string tCode = string.Empty;

                using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    reader.Read();

                    tUser = reader["tUser"].ToString();
                    tCode = reader["tCode"].ToString();

                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["tUser"] = tUser.ToString();
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["tCode"] = tCode.ToString();
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 28800;
                }

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = String.Format("No user!");
                }

                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TempData["Message"] = "Login failed.Error - " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are using this information later, but simple fix could be:

```
using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(tUser))
                    {
                        tUser = reader["tUser"].ToString();
                        tCode += $";{reader["tCode"].ToString()}";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tCode += $";{reader["tCode"].ToString()}";
                    }
                }
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["tUser"] = tUser.ToString();
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["tCode"] = tCode.ToString();
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 28800;
            }
```

Your `tCode` will look like this: `D11SU1;D11SU2`, so you can split it later.

Comment: thanks for reply. i using this information later  for populated a drop down list according to the enabling code. I'm going to use a query with WHERE condition e.g. ` SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE tCode IN ('D11SU1','D11SU2') `. Is your suggestion useful for this situation?

Comment: I think so. You can get your codes back as array using : `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["tCode"].ToString().Split(';')`.

Comment: thanks. I have tried your suggestion. The Split string working corretly. But the problem is SQL because the query is `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE tCode IN (D11SU1,D11SU2)` and not `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE tCode IN ('D11SU1','D11SU2')`. Quotes are missing...

Comment: In that case, instead of splitting do that: `var codes = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["tCode"].ToString().Replace(";","','");`
`var query = $"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE tCode IN ('{codes}')"`
I'm assuming you are starting programming, but keep in mind, that this is not the best way. Read a little bit abou `SQL Injection`.